# rspec controller test can't byebug the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I've got this (passing) controller test:

```
   RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do
     ... 
     it do 
        patch :update, id: user.id.to_s, user: params
        expect(response).to be_redirect
        expect(assigns[:user]).to eq user
      end
```

I would like to debug the controller with a debugger, so I added byebug at the beginning of my controller

```
  def update
    byebug
    @user.attributes = user_params
    unless @user.changed?
      flash[:notice] = "No changes found in user"
      render :edit
    else
      if @user.save
        flash[:notice] = "User has been updated"
        redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
      else
        flash.now[:alert] = "User has not been updated"
        render :edit
      end
    end
  end
```

byebug doesn't pause execution there, I even tried replacing `byebug` with a `raise "update"` just to see wether things were passing by there. they are not.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not a slop error? Is the code here actually being called? You should also use assign_attributes and not the attributes= setter if you want dirty tracking to work properly.

Comment: I'd imagine there's a before_action or before_filter that's preventing this part of the code from being executed, normally an auth check

Answer (score 1):

I was in facts not logged in, so the controller actions were not executed because rspec failed authenticating.

a quick check to [devise manual](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-(and-RSpec))

and voilà, ensure you got in `rails_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

and have a `spec/support` file specifying:

```
  def login_admin
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
      sign_in FactoryBot.create(:admin) # Using factory bot as an example
    end
  end

  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
      user.confirm! # or set a confirmed_at inside the factory. Only necessary if you are using the "confirmable" module
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

Then just call the proper log in methods in the controller rspec test.